# how to create and customize new unit in rally

Tags: configuration, project-management, agile, rally

By default in Rally as a unit for estimation for stories is POINT. I would like to change it to something else, for example to Man days. So in setup-> Work-spaces & Projects -> Workspace1 --edit

Change field value "Plan Estimate Units" from "point" to "MD" (Man day).

But,.. there is a question, how the system can know that MD it is 8 hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is that the system won't know that your unit represents 8 hours. [The Rally help site](http://www.rallydev.com/help/glossary#plan_estimate) describes plan estimates as:

> The amount of effort estimated to complete a single user story. Plan estimates are represented by points, t-shirt sizes, or other systems. They do not correspond to task or man hours.

The system doesn't do any conversion of these estimates to or from time.

Comment: Ok. then if have story for 1 day (my points), and there is one task for 10 hours. How would I know that it is out of our estimate?

Comment: The system will not enforce this for you, but there are various pages that will allow you to show the "Task Estimate Total" for a user story if you choose to do the conversion and comparison yourself. The question is, how are you using these estimates? The goal should generally be to improve the quality of our higher level estimates so we can have a more predictable velocity. Check out [this article](http://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/116) for an interesting take on the value of task estimates.